# gem install permission problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
qichunren@zhaobak:~> gem install hpricot
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

Current login user is qichunren, and qichunre user have write permission with .gem dir.I would like to know why gem not install files into my home .gem dir first? Why my gem common first want to install files into /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For a systemwide Ruby install, become root. For example:

```
$ sudo gem install hpricot
```

However, the modern approach in many circumstances, including in development, is to use a tool that lets you easily install and use Ruby as a normal user. This lets you avoid having to become root. There are a few such tools, and the one I use is [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

```
# install rvm into your ~
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

# install latest version of ruby into your ~
$ rvm install ruby

# installs a gem into your ~
$ gem install $SOME_GEM_NAME
```

Comment: Do not use sudo because you will install them as root and not have access to them when you're using your normal user. Use RVM and gemsets.

Comment: e.g. `rvm gem install hpricot`

Comment: You might want to delete this answer. You'll keep the points, and save people a lot of headache.

Answer (score 195):

Try setting `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` to `~/.gem`,

For the current terminal session, just type:

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gem
export GEM_PATH=~/.gem
```

If you want these to be set whenever you open a terminal, add the above commands to your `~/.bashrc` file.

For a more comprehensive solution to setting up a custom ruby environment, see [this tutorial from Site5KB](http://kb.site5.com/ruby-2/how-to-setup-a-custom-rubygems-environment/), which describes using a `.gemrc` file.

Comment: This is the actual right answer. Don't go wielding sudo installing things if you don't have to.

Comment: The link in the answer seems to have changed. The first step from this guide accomplished the same thing for me though: http://kb.site5.com/ruby-on-rails/how-to-setup-a-custom-rubygems-environment

Comment: @MikeSlutsky Thanks for pointing that out. In the future, if you find a broken link (or a link that has changed and is no longer relevant), feel free to submit an "edit" suggestion if you think you have a decent replacement.

Comment: @meagar I updated link given by @Mike-Slutsky, but noticed that it is documentation for `.gemrc` configuration. For ruby gem novices, this is daunting, when I understand your solution to be the much simpler ones I added. The solution works for me, but as a ruby novice, please confirm that my changes are in line with your intent.

Comment: This is really helpful. Don't simply use sudo. Thanks.

Comment: Remember to add your GEM_PATH to the global PATH. This is what I do: `PATH=$HOME/.gems/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH
GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gems
GEM_PATH=$HOME/.gems:/var/lib/gems/2.1.0:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
export PATH GEM_HOME GEM_PATH`

Answer (score 13):

I was getting this error on my shared server through 1and1 hosting. 
my solution was adding the `--user-install` option, which just installs it for your logged in user (which is all you need in a shared server environment)
example;  installing sass

```
gem install sass --user-install
```

Comment: Interestingly, I'm getting this error although I *have* specified `--user-install`.

Comment: I was banging my head for the gem install with Jenkins this helped me... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you're using rbenv and this is happening, you need to add the following to your .bash_profile:

```
export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"

if [ -d $RBENV_ROOT ]; then
  export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

re-install ruby resolve my problem.

```
brew install ruby
```