# Need to use Root to do "gem update --system"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, command-line-interface

Runnin 10.04 64bit Ubuntu.  I have a deploy user, and have no problems with "bundle install" but had to update gems and tried this:

```
deploy@pluto:/opt/ruby/bin$ gem update --system
```

error:

```
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-1.8.10.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

Tried with sudo:

```
deploy@pluto:/opt/ruby/bin$ sudo gem update --system
[sudo] password for deploy: 
sudo: gem: command not found
```

Then logged in as root, and no problem!?

```
root@pluto:/opt/ruby/bin# gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-1.8.10.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.10
Installing RubyGems 1.8.10
RubyGems 1.8.10 installed
```

This is my $PATH variable with and without sudo, any ideas what's wrong?

```
deploy@pluto:~$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

deploy@pluto:~$ echo $PATH
/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: run **which gem**, get that path and use it on the sudo call.

Comment: I found this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619695/gem-install-permission-problem  - someone says not to use sudo, or the regular user won't have access to them, is that true?

Comment: What method did you use to install Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need `sudo` to install gems. Looks like when you first installed Ruby/Rails, you used sudo. This installs ruby/rails in folders that are siblings to the `home` folder. There are multiple resources that tell you how to set up Ruby/Rails on a Ubuntu box only resource that worked for me (i followed these instructions to install Rails on 4 Ubuntu boxes) was Toran Billups article [here](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2010/09/01/How-to-install-Rails-3.0-and-Ruby-1.9.2-on-Ubuntu). Read it carefully and you should have a good environment set up.