# refineryCMS install error

Tags: ubuntu, refinerycms

(sorry for my english)
I tried to install with `gem install refinerycms`
its drop:

> Fetching: acts_as_indexed-0.7.8.gem (100%) ERROR:  While executing gem
>   ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.

I have Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [gem install permission problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619695/gem-install-permission-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You may just have a permissions issue.
[gem install permission problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619695/gem-install-permission-problem)
I think the last answer with 29+ is probably what you want to look at.