# Error while installing haml

Tags: ruby, rubygems, haml

I just felt like learning haml so first installed ruby using my terminal
this is my ruby version installed : `ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]`

When i run this command : `gem install haml` 
i get this error :

```
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ gem install haml
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Can anyone tell me where am i going wrong??

Comment: I guess you're trying to install a gem on a system ruby (no rvm/rbenv?) I've never really used system ruby in 3 years, but I think you have to `sudo gem install` in order to do that. Installing a Ruby manager such as RVM or RBenv is worth it if you want to do more than just have fun. Otherwise, have fun exploring!

Comment: Hey @JonathanAllard it worked thanks alot for your quick response ..

Comment: No problem. See [*Gem install permission problem*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619695/gem-install-permission-problem) for more info. (marked as duplicate)

Comment: I don't think you should be modifying the system ruby because if you screw it up, you'll screw up your system.  Install a more recent ruby version for yourself to play around with it.  Check out rvm or rbenv to do that.  After that never do `sudo gem install ...`, just do `gem install ...`