# Ruby on Rails bundler JSON error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, installation, bundle

So while doing bundle install I get a JSON error saying

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

then I try

```
gem install json -v 1.8.6
```

but it spits out

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

Why does it do this and why cant I bundle install

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619731/1949363 try changing you GEMPATH to be in a location your user has access. You could use `sudo` but will likely lead to access issues later.

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gem
export GEM_PATH=~/.gem
```