# Error installing SASS gem - don't have permissions

Tags: ruby, terminal, sass, rubygems

I'm not well versed in terminal, but I'll try my best to make this as clear and concise as I can.

I'm trying to install **SASS** and get the following errors:

When using `gem install sass` I get .

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

When using `sudo gem install sass` I get .

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

I have **Xcode** installed and I have agreed to the terms.

I even tried updating my Ruby, but terminal tells me I already have the most updated version.

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
```

The worst part of all of this is that when I navigate to my **Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems** directory, there is a `sass-3.5.5` folder!!! (linked image to follow)

[Ruby directory path to sass folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3lM6.png)

I try running `sass -v` and get `-bash: sass: command not found`

I feel like I've tried everything that I can think of or find online. I'm at a loss and definitely need some help.

Comment: Have you installed rvm?

Answer (score 2):

The issue can be fixed by installing RVM or Rbenv for managing ruby versions and gems.

Also, FilePermissionError can be fixed using the  -n parameter

```
sudo gem install sass -n /usr/bin
```

Comment: I've not installed either of those. I don't feel confident in terminal and I'm scared I might mess up Ruby somehow. I'll read the documentation and try that.   I'll also try the -n command.

Comment: Its better you use RVM or Rbenv for managing ruby versions and gems, otherwise, it will be become a headache to maintain multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not touching `sudo` command, so I managed to solve this issue by referring to [SASS home page](https://sass-lang.com/install):

> If you use Node.js, you can also install Sass using npm by running
>
> `npm install -g sass`

If you find it helpful, kindly upvote or leave comment so that I know it can solve your issues too.

Answer (score 1):

Or one could update the directory for where gems are installed.

Please see the origional answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619731/3302764

`export GEM_HOME=~/.gem
export GEM_PATH=~/.gem`